# node.js app not listening on port

Tags: node.js, upstart

I want to make my node.js app running at boot time, I used upstart and followed the instruction as below:

```
#!upstart
description "node.js server"
author      "joe"

start on startup
stop on shutdown

script
    export HOME="/root"

    echo $$ > /var/run/myprogram.pid
    exec sudo -u username /usr/local/bin/node /where/myprogram.js >> /var/log/yourprogram.sys.log 2>&1
end script

pre-start script
    # Date format same as (new Date()).toISOString() for consistency
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Starting" >> /var/log/yourprogram.sys.log
end script

pre-stop script
    rm /var/run/myprogram.pid
    echo "[`date -u +%Y-%m-%dT%T.%3NZ`] (sys) Stopping" >> /var/log/yourprogram.sys.log
end script
```

when I call `start myprogram`, it says "start/running, process 16995", however when I use `netstat -l`, I didn't see my app listening on the port that I set in myprogram.js. And when I say `stop myprogram`, it prompts "stop: Unknown instance:".

Any idea what might be wrong?

Comment: Anything in your log file that you're appending to?

Comment: On which port is your application listening? Is there anything in /var/log/upstart/myprogram.log and/or /var/log/syslog that might be helpful?

Comment: Is the node app actually running with pid 16995? I had an issue with one of my node apps where upstart got the wrong pid. I had to add "expect fork" (basically means "get the pid of the second started pid".